# ng-repeat over a div not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have used `ng-repeat` numerous times already in the past, but for some reason I cannot yet understand why it is not on the following situation:

I have an array of objects called registers which I am referencing on the `ng-repeat` but nothing happens.

I know the array is populated because I have seen it on numerous `console.log`  and because it works if I move the `ng-repeat` over to the `<tbody>`

```
<div ng-repeat = "r in registers">
        <!-- START HEADER -->
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Denise Watson</td>
            </tr>

                </tbody> <!-- END HEADER -->
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"></td>
                        <td>
                        <!-- Summernote Container -->
                            <div class="js-summernote-air">
                                 <p>End of air-mode area!</p>
                            </div>

                       </td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
            <!--  END TABLE -->
        </div>
```

I was hoping someone could tell me if there is something I may be ignoring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u checked if registers ng-repeat = "r in registers" have value. check if its empty

Comment: its not working on tbody? you placed in div and asking for tbody

Comment: First confirm that it has value make a simple <h1>{{r}}</h1> for checking

Comment: Here before tbody tag you should place a <table > tag

Comment: It has a value, I already confirmed it via a console.log and by repeating a <p>

Comment: It works if I use the ng-repeat on the <table> that encompass the table body, the problem is that it makes a new table for each element, I was hoping to have a different body per entry.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle? I just recreated your situation and it seems to work for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/sniels/qzcegttn/.
Although it does seem to work, I'd suggest you wrap tbody in a table, and only use one tbody and one thead, currently you're using tbody twice.

Comment: @sniels it seems you're right and there is no way around, I cannot repeat tbodies inside a single table. If you post your solution I'll accept it as theanswer.

Comment: always use track by in ngRepeat and in ngOptions to avoid duplication errors and to improve performance. Source : angular docs

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper Though it does seem to work in the fiddle I provided. I think pgreen2 is correct in his answer. I didn't use a table in my fiddle because I didn't see that in your code.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper the answer you marked i have mentioned same thing in my comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I just ran into this same problem.  It stems from `<div>` not being a valid elment within a `<table>`.

I'm guessing that since you have `<tbody>` there, that there is a `<table>` tag that was left out of your snippet.  `<div>`s aren't allowed in a table, so the browser moves it before the table.  In my situation, doing this, causes the angular scope to change so that there was nothing to iterate over.  You can verify this by using the developer tools of your browser.

So, my guess is that you probably want to move the `ng-repeat` onto the `<tbody>` or `<table>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ng-repeat in "div" tag means use "span" 
inside div tag.  instead of using "table"  and its sub attributes..

else use your ng-repeat inside "table" or "thead" or "tr" also 
it will iterate rows ...

than only ng-repeat will works.